# Python URL end string counter

Tags: python, url, extract, counter

I went back to one of my old projects in Python, but I seem to have forgotten how I managed to extract my data, if anyone can point me to the right direction and the documentations to implement this, it would be grateful.

I implemented a web crawler that extracts information from the HTML page by scanning my html code.  The URL of mywebsite.com/product=1 is scanned using BeautifulSoup and urllib2 libraries that I have used.

But I want to have mywebsite.com to increment to a maximum of 10.  How exactly can I extract, read and replace the end of the url and replace this???     I noticed others implemented urlparse library to replace the domain main, but it is not the same as my approach.

```
>  mywebsite.com/product=1  
>  mywebsite.com/product=2 
>  mywebsite.com/product=3  
>  mywebsite.com/product=4  .. 
>  mywebsite.com/product=10
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to loop through and crawl 10 times?

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    url = r"mywebsite.com/product=" + str(i)
    url = r"mywebsite.com/product={}".format(i) # or use str.format
    print(url)

    # crawl and extract
```